# How to partially deserialise a JSON object?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have a JSON object:

```
{"content":{"foo":1,"bar":2},"signature":"3f5ab1..."}
```

Deserialising this into a custom type already works fine, using:

```
let s: SignedContent = serde_json::from_str(string)?;
```

What I want is `{"foo":1,"bar":2}` as a `&[u8]` slice, so that I can check the signature.

(I am aware of the issues around canonical JSON representations, and have mitigations in place.)

Currently I am wastefully *re-serialising* the `Content` object (within the `SignedContent` object) into a string and getting the octets from that.

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`serde_json::value::RawValue`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html) (which is available with the "raw_value" feature).

> Reference to a range of bytes encompassing a single valid JSON value in the input data.
>
> A `RawValue` can be used to defer parsing parts of a payload until later, or to avoid parsing it at all in the case that part of the payload just needs to be transferred verbatim into a different output object.
>
> When serializing, a value of this type will retain its original formatting and will not be minified or pretty-printed.

With usage being:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct SignedContent<'a> {

    #[serde(borrow)]
    content: &'a RawValue,

    // or without the 'a
    //content: Box<RawValue>
}
```

You can then use `content.get()` to get the raw `&str`.